# Walkthrough of regex match

Tags: regex

Could someone help me understand how a regex engine matches the following:

```
a(bc)*
```

Against the text: `abc`.

For example, how many steps does it take? What happens at each step? For example, something like:

- The first step is to match the letter "a" from the regex against the "a" in the text "abc". Because this is not optional/repeated there is no backtrack stored at this position.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html has some useful examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, the regular expression (if it is a true regular expression) is first converted to a graph representation of an NFA (non-deterministic finite automaton), perhaps something like this:

```
a(bc)*:

(0)-- a --> (1) ---b--> (2) -- ε --> ((3)) 
             ^           |
              `-----c----'
```

0 is the start state; ((3)) is the acceptance state.  ε is an empty transition without consuming input.

An NFA can be executed directly by the NFA simulation algorithm.

It can also be compiled to a DFA (deterministic F. A.) using the "subset construction". The states of the DFA correspond to sets of the original NFA states. We end up with something like this:

```
DFA state    NFA States    Input Next State
--------------------------------------------
0            { 0 }         a     1
1            { 1 }         b     2
2 (accept)   { 2, 3 }      c     1
```

State 2 of the DFA corresponds to two states of the NFA: when the DFA is instate 2, the corresponding NFA simulator has to be in states 2 and 3 simultaneously, because 3 is reachable via an epsilon transition (no input symbol consumed). The DFA state 2 is an acceptance state because the NFA set it corresponds to { 2, 3 } contains an acceptance state.

The DFA requires very few steps; basically we just read characters and dispatch to the next state in the table based on the current state and the input character. If we are not able to dispatch, then there is a mismatch; we can stop reading more input. If we process the entire input, and are left in an acceptance state, then there is a match.